# (AppleScript) Is it possible to script a dialog box where it shows a random string of characters every time you see it?

Tags: applescript

When you click 'OK' on a dialogue box (or something similar) it shows a dialogue box that has a randomly generated line of characters.

Comment: Did you mean to show a dialog box with an OK button, and when clicked, another dialog is shown with the randomly generated line of characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
set theChars to {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}

display dialog "Let's go. Click \"OK\" button to generate random word."
if button returned of result is not "OK" then return

repeat
    set randomWord to ""
    repeat (random number 10) times
        set randomWord to randomWord & some item of theChars
    end repeat
    display dialog randomWord
end repeat
```

Answer (score -2):

```
set theChars to {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}
set theRandomWord to ""
repeat 5 times
    set theRandomWord to (theRandomWord & some item of theChars)
end repeat

display dialog (theRandomWord)
```